# instagram grid master - fetch and link images to instagram URL

Tags: instagram

In my search for a responsive Instagram feed grid, I settled on the following plugin:
https://github.com/cmaseattle/instagram-grid

It was the only one that I found that fetched the like count for each photo.

However, I'm totally lost on how to configure it to fetch the URL of each instagram item (not the direct img link) and then reference that by linking each of the grid items to their appropriate instagram page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, I figured this out with an amalgamation of code snippets

Changed line 116 from

```
like.innerHTML='<img src="http://cmaseattle.github.io/instagram-grid/insta-heart.png" class="insta-heart">'+d.data[i].likes.count;
```

to

```
like.innerHTML='<a target="_blank" href="' +d.data[i].link +'"><span class="link-spanner"></span><img src="http://cmaseattle.github.io/instagram-grid/insta-heart.png" class="insta-heart">'+d.data[i].likes.count;

.link-spanner{
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I also added the following styles to the likes hover div

```
.insta-likes {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */    
}
```